# matrix with Variable and constant value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to use matrix `pa` with 4 variables(`x1`,... from another function) and 2 constant numbers in a for loop like this:

```
pa=[x1,x2,x3,x4,1,3];
```

I defined `pa` :

```
pa=zeros(1209,6);
```

This code without constant numbers works perfectly (`pa=[x1,x2,x3,x4]`).
But when I want  to use constant numbers, I have this error :

> Error using ==> horzcat
>   CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Could anyone help me why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're trying to concatenate two matrices of different sizes:

- `x1`,`x2`,etc of size `1209x1`
- your constant numbers which have size `1x1`

Fix it by expanding the constant numbers:

```
ct_mat = ones(length(x1),1)*[1 3];
pa = [x1 x2 x3 x4  ct_mat];
```